# Can't set value in web form using "value='foo'" but enter values manually is fine?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I try to set the value for a couple of fields in a web form using something like

```
document.getElementsByName('form[493202]')[0].value="Foo"
```

If I execute this in the browser console the field is updated, but if I then click the field manually it is reverted to an old value. The old value is something I entered manually.

This is the weird thing - if I enter a value manually everything works as expected, including submitting the form, but if I use JS to enter values and then submit the form, I get complaints that the fields are empty (a kind of "compromise" between these results occur if I first enter values manually and then change the values using JS. If I then click submit the values are reverted to the values I entered manually.), despite, visually, the fields aren't empty - BUT the fields are emptied when I click submit (manually entered values remain after I click submit).

**What is going on here? How can I enter values that are "accepted" by this form using JS?**

[image: Short clip displaying the issue: I have used the code above to enter Foo in the field. When I click that field the value is reverted to the last manually entered value.]

Some HTML from the form, the "header" as well as this specific field:

```
<form data-v-9454ea52="" id="form-gameflow-105529" data-form-id="form-gameflow-105529" class="content__item content__item--form invalid" autocomplete="">
<div data-v-9454ea52="" class="content__item-form-element col-12 content__item-form-element--text">
  <div class="content__item-form-type content__item-form-type--text">
    <!---->
    <div class="content__item-form-group content__item-form-group--text form-group form-group--has-value form-group--valid">
      <label class="content__item-form-label content__item-form-label--text">Name</label>
      <input class="content__item-form-text form-control" type="text" name="form[493202]" placeholder autocomplete="off" data-ddg-inputtype="unknown">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Given that HTML, `document.getElementsByName('from[493202]')[0].value="Foo"` is working as expected for me.    Based on your description (I can't see your image, Imgur is blocked for me here) your form submit handler is doing something nonstandard; possibly you're depending on `change` events on the form fields which aren't triggered by setting the values via code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the library you use to validate whether the form is empty is not being updated when you change the value using JavaScript.

You need to likely trigger the `input` event (and maybe `change` event) to let these validation libraries know you have filled out the form.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var field = document.getElementsByName('form[493202]')[0];
  field.value = "Foo"

  // Trigger the oninput event
  var inputEvent = new Event('input');
  field.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);

  // Trigger the onchange event
  var changeEvent = new Event('change');
  field.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
}
```

```html
<form data-v-9454ea52="" id="form-gameflow-105529" data-form-id="form-gameflow-105529" class="content__item content__item--form invalid" autocomplete="">
  <div data-v-9454ea52="" class="content__item-form-element col-12 content__item-form-element--text">
    <div class="content__item-form-type content__item-form-type--text">
      <!---->
      <div class="content__item-form-group content__item-form-group--text form-group form-group--has-value form-group--valid">
        <label class="content__item-form-label content__item-form-label--text">Name</label>
        <input class="content__item-form-text form-control" type="text" name="form[493202]" placeholder autocomplete="off" data-ddg-inputtype="unknown">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<button type="button" onClick="myFunction()">click me</button>
```

Comment: Hmm, your code worked once. I changed the value to "Foo" using my code above, pasted your code into the browser console and pressed enter. Then I entered `myFucntion()`. Now when I click the field `foo` remains. However, I then changed the value to `bar` using the same code, followed by a new call to `myFunction()` but now when I click in this field (that displays `bar`), it is reverted to `foo`(earlier it was reverted to `uiouo`)!?!? Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: @d-b The issue is other JavaScript code that is running. Start removing JS scripts from the page to narrow down which script(s) are causing the issue

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not my page. I am scripting a browser to fill in a form on an external page.

Comment: @d-b Hmm, in that case, I would need a demo of the problem to debug futher.

Comment: After some more testing, your code worked fine.